# Custom filter in Magento's layered navigation

Tags: magento

I have a list of alpha-numeric size attributes that I need to be able to filter, either in advanced search or in layered navigation (I'm referring to Magento, if anyone else decides to remove that from the title).

the problem is that I should be able to set them as intervals. Imagine shoe sizes: 25, 25/, 31, 31/. I would like to be able to set something like:

```
20-25/
26-30
30/-40
```

With the first filter returning all shoes available in that size interval, obviously. How can I achieve this?

It occurred to me assigning thos intervals as attributes before I export them from SQL Server... Maybe that would save me some trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't have an option to make attributes as intervals, only the price attribute is filtered like that.
I think you can do this with 2 attributes: first would be shoe size, and show this one only in the product details page, so you would list values like 25/26/27... and the second would be shoe size interval, an show this one in layered navigation/search and have values like 25-30/30-35/35-40... both of them would be dropdowns in the admin area.

You can make a module that extends Magento's default navigation, you have to rewrite filters block and model from catalog in frontend and attributes from admin so that you can add an extra option to the attribute like "interval".

Comment: Thanks. Way too much for me. I did it automatically at the SQL Server level, before exporting. I took advantage of the fact that sizes have their own IDs, from 31 to 100. I just segmented them based on those IDs, that obviously are numeric.